# licence check failed message

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to add google games services into my app, and i'm having an error "License check failed" and i can't figure out what went what wrong, as i didn't found similar probeleme or documentation on it..

here's the logcat:

```
5-16 07:34:13.627 2915-4030/com.google.android.gms E/SignInIntentService: Game 757739709867 not licensed to player.
                                                                           com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.server.GamesServer.getResponseBlocking(GamesServer.java:174)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.server.api.PlayersApi.getBlocking(PlayersApi.java:86)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.getPlayerFromNetwork(PlayerAgent.java:1693)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.fetchPlayer(PlayerAgent.java:644)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.DataBroker.loadSelf(DataBroker.java:1185)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$LoadSelfOperation.executeInternal(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:294)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$BaseOperation.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:56)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$OperationAdapter.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:520)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.chimera.BaseAsyncOperationService$OperationTask.run(BaseAsyncOperationService.java:177)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.PriorityRunnable.run(PriorityRunnable.java:17)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-16 07:34:13.657 3934-3934/com.google.android.play.games.ui I/SignInActivity: Transition from 8 to 11
05-16 07:34:13.658 3934-3934/com.google.android.play.games.ui W/SignInActivity: onSignInFailed()...
05-16 07:34:13.658 3934-3934/com.google.android.play.games.ui W/SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 8
05-16 07:34:13.658 3934-3934/com.google.android.play.games.ui W/SignInActivity: ==> Returning non-OK result: 10003
05-16 07:34:13.684 2915-2972/com.google.android.gms W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 8487000, Services 10299470, and Games 39080070
```

[image]
I changed the Google account in the emulator but the error remains..

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have [Anti-Piracy](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy) enabled for the app?  I believe it will detect that the emulator is not an actual device and the app was not installed from the play store, thus triggering the license check.

Comment: That because i didn't publish the app (apk file) in google play store. Thank you a lot!! Is their in vacancy available with you guys..just any job. :)